# A better \sum limits display style?

Tags: equations, subscripts, displaystyle

Consider the following

```
y_j=\sum_{k=0}^n \sum_{i=\max(-k,1-j)}^{\min(k,n-j)} x_{j+i}
```

[image]

I do not like the second summation limits style. Is there any better alternative to this?

Comment: Change the notation? Define somewhere `$l = max(-k,1-j)$` and write the inner sum als `$\sum_{i=l}^{min(k,n-j)}$`?

Comment: As Oleg mentions, it seems better to use the `to ease notation we set ...` approach.

Comment: I look for excuses to end sentences with `where $l = max(-k,1-j)$.` to avoid putting punctuation in display math.